# Best database for storing statistics from Erlang

Tags: database, erlang

I need to choose a database for storing statistical data (in fact this is a series of timestamp-value data). I understand that virtually any database can handle this, but there are a couple of requirements:

- it should be fast;
- it should be able to handle A LOT of
  data (10s of gigabytes) and splice it
  fast;
- it should have a stable, maintained
  and handy interface to Erlang;
- it should be available from Python;
- it should be able to make something
  like the thing named "capped
  collections" in mongodb: collection
  with the capped size, with old data
  being rewritten if the size reach the
  limit.

I thought about mongo, but emongo seems to be a little dead - the last commit was made 7 months ago.

Comment: Yes, but I'll be glad to hear about another alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

[Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/) may be a good choice (here's a [Riak comparison to MongoDB](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak-Compared-to-MongoDB.html)). It's written in Erlang, is distributed, fault tolerant and scales linearly. It has [clients](http://wiki.basho.com/Client-Libraries.html) for Erlang, Javascript, Java, PHP, Python, Ruby. A REST interface, a protobuf interface and so many other goodies (Map Reduce, links, replication, pre/post commit hooks, ...). It's open source and is created maintained by [Basho](http://www.basho.com/). Basho has [commercial offering](http://www.basho.com/products_riak_overview.php) of Riak as well with some extra features (like multi-site replication, SNMP monitoring, etc) but there's awsome value in the OS version.

Depending on your needs  it may make sense to combine a couple of technologies. For example you could front your system with an in memory store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) for speed and use Riak to persist the data. Redis + Riak is a pretty sweet stack.

Comment: Basho has some smart people working for the them. Rusty Klophaus of Nitrogen fame and and the Webmachine guys. Oh yea and rebar came out of Basho too (dizzyd!).

Answer (score 1):

I think postgresql and [pgsql](https://github.com/noss/pgsql/tree) driver it will be best solution for you.

Comment: can you explain your advice please?

Comment: I use mnesia and couchdb in my project and this db not very suited for large data sets. Then postgresql have driver to python. I use pgsql/erlang in my work in heavily message server and postgresql has not yet been complaints

Comment: i dont think it's good idea to use relational databases to handle statistical data, it's just completely different approach

Comment: The thing with databases(traditional) is that they can store data in ordered form on disk. They where optimized for it. When ordered we often have a very good cache hit ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Files on disk, rotated, will serve your demands fine. The point is you don't want to search data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

[redis](http://redis.io/) is quite a close contender.

The only current limitation is the size of the dataset, which has to be either store in full in memory or use the VM method, in which only the key space has to fit in memory (however a bit of spare room for actual data would be nice) but has a very slow startup time.

Antirez, the developer, is rewriting the backend into something called [diskstore](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/d444bc786689bde9?pli=1) which should solve your issue. It's not baked yet, but I have a lot of confidence in this project.

About the capped collections, redis does not have a direct way for handling that. But the [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) function can help you out.